# Should ampersands in JS and CSS links use HTML entities?

Tags: html

I've read various posts and blogs stating that ampersands need not use HTML entities when used in JavaScript (and presumably CSS) links.  Yet, when I validate the script using https://validator.w3.org/, it shows as an error.  Please advise.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <link href="file1.css?x=1&y=2" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="file2.css?x=1&amp;y=2" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="file1.js?x=1&y=2" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="file2.js?x=1&amp;y=2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have misinterpreted your sources. Ampersands must be encoded *anywhere* they appear within an HTML document, including URLs. This means your first `<script>` tag and your first `<link>` tag are both invalid, while the second are acceptable. This is because you're dealing with markup, not the scripts or stylesheets themselves.

If the ampersand is part of the literal URL itself or a query string value then it needs to be percent-encoded to `%26`, otherwise it must be HTML encoded to `&amp;` (usually when it appears as a query string *separator*, as is the case in your example).

The only place where they do not need to be HTML-encoded is *within JavaScript and CSS files*, so long as they exist outside of any HTML markup altogether.

Comment: Either I misinterpreted it or it was bogus advice.  Either way, thank you for your clarification.

Comment: Very thorough explanation.